# Word to describe something that focusses so ostentatiously on its purpose that it fails to achieve its goal

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

For example, if I go and see a movie that I perceive to have placed so much effort on the artistic merit of the acting and cleverness of the storyline that it is difficult to call it a success as a movie.

Comment: You just described Primer http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0390384/

Comment: Possibly vainglorious? But I'd prefer to coin a new word "grandelinquent" (similar in form to grandiloquent).

Comment: I would describe the situation as *ironic*.

Comment: Overegged pudding? Gilded lily? Overblown? We must have hundreds of expressions for this context.

Comment: Would perfectionism work? Although in that case, it's usually that the work fails to be completed because of the obsession with detail.

Comment: Why not _ostentatious_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for a term like *affected*.

> **affected** |əˈfektid|
>   *adjective*
>   2 artificial, pretentious, and designed to impress: *the gesture appeared both affected and stagy*. *[NOAD]*

Answer (score 4):

Too artful or contrived. Too clever by half(BrE). Up its own arse(BrE, vulg.)

Comment: Is "too clever by half" only BrE?

Answer (score 3):

Consider *[hubristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubris)*, the adjectival form of *hubris*.  Wikipedia says:

> Hubris... means extreme haughtiness, pride or arrogance. Hubris often indicates a loss of contact with reality and an overestimation of one's own competence or capabilities...

Also consider *[Icarus-like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icarus)*, as the myth of Icarus is often seen as a "tragic example of hubris or failed ambition".

Some words or phrases that might appear in reviews include *misguided, flawed* (or *failed*) *vision, imperfect, overthought, unsound, arrogant, overreaching* and synonyms of same.

Answer (score 1):

It might be detractive , detractory. Detract= To reduce the value, importance, or quality of something. Often used with from:

> Testimony that only detracts from the strength of the plaintiff's case.
>   Her anger detracts from her beauty

In another sense it might be "distractive". Distract=To cause to turn away from the original focus of attention or interest.

Comment: *Detract* is often used in the sense you cite, but frankly I doubt I've ever heard or read *detractive* or *detractory* in my whole life up to now. I've just discovered through NGrams that *detractory* was (rarely) used a couple of centuries ago, and *detractive* doesn't look exactly "current" either.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: From Wordnet database, detracive (adj): causing to decrease in importance or value. I agree with you that the usage rate is low.

Comment: Well I'm certainly not denying that *detractive , detractory* are/were actually "valid words". And a low usage rate doesn't mean a word shouldn't be promoted here (I see nothing wrong with [crapulent](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=crapulent&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), for example). It's the fact that they've largely [fallen into disuse](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=detractive%2Cdetractory&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) that bothers me about these two inflected forms of the perfectly ordinary word *detract*.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that the people who made the movie

> [couldn't see the forest for the trees,](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/see_the_forest_for_the_trees)

meaning they were too focused on details to worry about the big picture.

Comment: +1 for [not seeing the bigger picture](http://www.idiomquest.com/learn/idiom/big-picture/) - definitely apposite in OP's context!

Answer (score 0):

***misplugged***, to coin a word.

[see **[plug](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/plug_4)** *verb* ( ADVERTISE ) UK US /plʌg/]

Plugging is rampant. It could be the right focus or misplaced focus. Overemphasizing the wrong aspect leads to diversion.

Answer (score 0):

Heavy-handed comes to mind.